A boolean for hidden orders with certain tickers
I would like to place hidden orders on buy limit orders with ccxt. However, hidden orders are only allowed with certain tickers. Is there a way to check if the ticker I want to trade allows hidden orders, so I can include hidden: True directly in my order parameters?
Thank you!
kucoin.create_order(ticker, 'limit', 'buy', amountToFill, entryPrice, params={'timeInForce': 'GTT','cancelAfter':10,'hidden':True,"remark":remark})

